# The app didn't start in the required time

Tags: windows-phone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've created a windows app with appcelerator Titanium. The app runs fine in all the emulators but when I run it on the device it crashes immedeately (only the splashscreen is being displayed). The error message in the console is:

The app didn't start in the required time

Any idea what the cause of this error can be?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how long does it take for the UI to start in simulator?

Comment: There was an old windows update that fixed this for certain apps with long load times on devices. Is your device fully up to date with all the patches?